# get script tags with jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the contents of a div from another page using $.get() method of jQuery.
When the content is an iframe, the following code works, but when they are scripts, not selected any content.

```
function updateVideo() {
    $.get("index.php?c=watch", function(data){
        var video = $(data).find("#video").html();
        $('#content').html(video);
    }, 'html');
    return false;
}
```

examples of possible content of data:

```
<div id="video"> <!-- works -->
    <iframe src="..." />
</div>
```

or

```
<div id="video"> <!-- not works -->
    <script>var u = 56; var y = 'dfghjk'; // ... </script>
    <script src="..."></script>
</div>
```

Anyone know how to solve the problem?

Comment: EDIT: sry. I think I explained myself badly. this example are two examples of two possible answers. the script works when the result is a html tags, but not when you have the script tag.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead since `find` searches through *descendants*:

```
$(data).filter("#video").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

why do you have 2 same id's !!???

this is the problem.

you should make the id unique

Comment: Also, the ID should be "video", not "#video", but the 2 divs are there to show 2 cases explained in the question not as example of a single page

Comment: sry. I think I explained myself badly. this example are two examples of two possible answers. the script works when the result is a html tags, but not when you have the script tag.